# Name 'self' is not Defined in Python

Tags: python-2.7

Can anyone tell me what I need to do to resolve the "Name 'self' not defined" error I'm getting on the line identified below?:

```
class FulfillWhseOrderAction(object):

    def __init__(self, name):
        self._action_name = name
        self._as = actionlib.SimpleActionServer(self._action_name, pkg_commands.msg.FulfillWhseOrderAction, execute_cb=self.execute_cb)
        self._as.start()

    # *** ERROR HAPPENING HERE: ***
    rospy.loginfo('%s: Executing warehouse order' % self._action_name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    rospy.init_node('node_ReceiveWhseOrder')
    FulfillWhseOrderAction(rospy.get_name())
    rospy.spin()
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm lost.  Where exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `self` is a variable(call it an object) sent to the `__init__` function. So you cannot access it from outside the function. Indent the error occuring line to be inside the function.

```
class FulfillWhseOrderAction(object):

    def __init__(self, name):
        self._action_name = name
        self._as = actionlib.SimpleActionServer(self._action_name,  pkg_commands.msg.FulfillWhseOrderAction, execute_cb=self.execute_cb)
        self._as.start()

    # *** ERROR HAPPENING HERE: ***
        rospy.loginfo('%s: Executing warehouse order' % self._action_name)

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        rospy.init_node('node_ReceiveWhseOrder')
        FulfillWhseOrderAction(rospy.get_name())
        rospy.spin()
```

This will save the problem